# Are dioxins the most toxic chemicals known to science?

Tags: chemistry, safety, toxicology

Dioxins are implicated in The [Seveso disaster](http://www.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,1986457_1986501_1986449,00.html) in Italy and the lingering disputes about deformities and birth defects caused by the use of the Agent Orange defoliant in the Vietnam war ([Wikipedia summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Orange)). They are often described as the most toxic chemicals known to man ([example](http://www.ejnet.org/dioxin/), [another example](http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/motm/dioxin/dioxin-hp.htm)).

Not everyone agrees (see [this paper](http://www8.nationalacademies.org/onpinews/newsitem.aspx?RecordID=11688)). And prominent people have survived poisoning with them such as former Ukrainian president [Viktor Yushchenko](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/europe/4088345.stm).

So do dioxins deserve their public image as one of the worst toxins?

Comment: Just released: http://www.epa.gov/iris/supdocs/dioxinv1sup.pdf

Comment: Wikipedia claims that [Botulinium Toxin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin) (Botulism) is the most powerful *neurotoxin* ever discovered, and is up there among the most toxic substances. There are many kinds of toxins, if you wish to keep your question to toxic *chemicals* (and man made ones at that?), you should explicitly say so (your last line implies naturally occurring is okay). There are a lot of naturally occurring toxins.

Comment: I read Plutonium is the most toxic substance, but I'm not sure how valid the source is. If I remember right, it was Robert Jungk, "Brighter Than a Thousand Suns", 1956.

Comment: @userunknown: This claim was addressed here: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18230/is-plutonium-the-most-toxic-substance-known-to-man

Comment: @Oddthinking: If you (or somebody else) change the question, my answers or comments might not fit any longer. That's by the way the reason the policy is against fundamental changes to the question. See also: First (motor) flight.

Comment: @userunknown: I think there's been a misunderstanding here. I am not proposing any change to this question (and I don't see an answer from you). My comment was that your half-remembered claim in the above comment about Plutonium from 2012 was specifically addressed in a separate question in 2013.

Comment: @Oddthinking: The question was changed from "the most toxic" to "among the most toxic". This might change valid answers from "No" to "Yes" and is a bad habit, especially 2 years after the question was postet. Instead of commenting to my comment which is now rendered inappropriate you should probably address the change of the question instead.

Comment: @user_unknown: I've reverted the change for you. I thought the change was pretty innocuous and irrelevant; it didn't undermine any answers because there weren't any at the time. In any case, it is irrelevant to my comment which was addressing *your* claim, which is wrong, whether it is appropriate or not.

Comment: @userunknown I don't want to get into a reversion war on the title wording but the problem with arguing as you do is that it makes it easy to miss the point while answering the question. In *logic* the two versions of the question are very different, in *normal english usage* they are not. I didn't originally intend to pose a question where the answer could be "no" because dioxins are incredibly toxic, but poisonium is 5% more toxic. The intent was to ask whether they were in the "really incredibly nasty" group or elsewhere.

Comment: In the case of dioxins, it makes no difference whether the question is "the most toxic" and "among the most toxic" - neither is even remotely close to being true.  It would be a valid point if the subject was botulinum toxin.

Comment: @Mark: Since the nature of a question is, that you don't know the answer when asking it, the difference is relevant. An answer might not be true - the change of the question will invalidate the meaning of the answer though.

Comment: @matt_black: If there is no difference in the question, don't change it. If you have a different question - state a new one!

Comment: @Oddthinking: My claim was, by all respect, that I have read plutonium to be the most toxic substance. No answer showed my claim to be wrong, but the claim cited by me, which is a little bit a different thing, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Dioxins are not particularly toxic to people but are deadly to Guinea Pigs and some other animals**

Note: many of the facts below are from a summary of Dioxin evidence in John Emsley's book *[The Consumer's Good Chemical Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Consumers-Good-Chemical-Guide-Jargon-free/dp/0716745054/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1389452190&sr=1-1&keywords=consumers%20good%20chemical%20guide)*.

One of the things about dioxins that creates unwarranted worry is that chemists have devised ways to detect them in incredibly small quantities (in the 1950s they were lucky to reliably detect parts per thousand; by the 1980s fractions of parts per trillion were easily detected). This means they can now be detected *almost everywhere*. They are also fairly stable (though they are broken down by some bugs and by the UV component of sunlight) and slightly volatile, so they do get around a lot.

It is also worth noting that there are a large range of different dioxins most of which are not at all toxic. The two archetypal nasty members of the class are shown below:

[image: two key dioxin structures]

There are nearly two hundred other dioxins which differ from the two shown by having different numbers and locations of the chlorines attached to the rings.

One of the reasons that caused concern about them was they they were significant contaminants in a range of chlorinated weedkillers ([2,4,5-T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,4,5-Trichlorophenoxyacetic_acid) and [2,4-D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,4-Dichlorophenoxyacetic_acid), for example, the major ingredients of Agent Orange). The wide use of these weedkillers exposed many people to their contaminants (both because of use and manufacture).

One of the reason dioxins came to be regarded as one of the most deadly known toxins is that they are, *to guinea pigs.* A dose of 1 micro-g per kg will kill guinea pigs. In hamsters, however, the toxic dose is 5,000 micro-g per kg and there good evidence that people are much less sensitive to them than this. As a reference, [botulinum toxin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin) (one of the nastiest known human toxins) kills people at a dose of 10 micro-g per kg.

While we can't do laboratory experiments on people to estimate the acute and chronic activity of dioxins, but we can estimate the effects from looking at people who have been accidentally exposed from chemical accidents. There have been several accidents in manufacturing plants and R&D labs, some of which exposed the public to dioxins.

The most obvious human effect of dioxin exposure is [chloracne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloracne) which is nasty but reversible. Emsley quotes Michael Gough, an expert on the topic:

> ...no human illness, other than the skin disease chloracne, which has occurred only on highly exposed people, has ever been convincingly associated with dioxins.

One big worry, though, is whether exposure might cause cancer in the longer term (dioxins *look* like the sort of things that might cause cancer). But as Gough [summarised](http://www.spiked-online.com/newsite/article/447#.UtFoHXkcXQU) more recently:

> There are fewer studies of ‘environmentally exposed’ people, primarily because there are few populations that have been exposed to higher than ‘background’ levels. The two most studied populations are those that lived around a chemical plant in Seveso, Italy, which blew up in 1976; and the residents of Times Beach, Missouri, which was exposed to dioxin-contaminated oil. These studies find that there are no increases in overall disease rates or cancers. It is possible to associate dioxin exposures with elevated occurrence of a specific cancer or disease in some studies, but the occurrence of other cancers and diseases is lower than expected, and there is little consistency among studies’ results. This suggests that the varying disease rates result from fluctuations of occurrence observed whenever small populations are studied.

Another fact putting dioxins in perspective has become apparent as analytical techniques have improved: they are *natural* compounds not just evil byproducts of the chemical industry. In fact we have been exposed to them since we invented fire and the natural world has had some level of dioxins in it since plants first burned, long before people appeared. This happens because wood and plants always contain some chloride (wood is 0.2% chloride) and, when material containing chlorine and carbon burns, dioxins are produced in small quantities. It may even be that people are particularly resistant to dioxins compared to some animals as we have been exposed to higher levels than most animals ever since we started using fire to cook.

**Summary**

While some animals are exquisitely sensitive to dioxins, the best evidence suggests people are not. And, while some dioxins cause nasty human diseases like chloracne, there is little evidence that any cause other conditions even when exposure is chronic. They are not near the top of the list as human toxins.

Comment: Good answer Matt.  An extreme example of human exposure is the Ukrainian politician Viktor Yushchenko who was the victim of an apparent assasination attempt by dioxin poisoning.  He suffered extreme chloracne and was hospitalized for an extended time, but appears to have recovered.  Dioxin levels in his blood were reported to be 50,000 times the normal level.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Yushchenko#Dioxin_poisoning_allegations  it's also interesting to note that according to the US EPA, the largest source of human-caused dioxin emissions is people burning trash in burn barrels.