# Is plutonium the most toxic substance known to man?

Tags: nuclear-energy, nuclear-weapons

According to "[The Myth of Plutonium Toxicity](http://www.fortfreedom.org/p22.htm)" by [Bernard L. Cohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Cohen_%28physicist%29):

> Plutonium is constantly referred to by the news media as ``the most
>   toxic substance known to man.''  Ralph Nader has said that a pound  of
>   plutonium  could cause  8  billion cancers,  and former Senator
>   Ribicoff  has said  that a  single particle  of plutonium inhaled into
>   the  lung can cause cancer.

Is plutonium "the most toxic substance known to man"?

Comment: Is it a small typo or does he really think a pound of plutonium can kill two billion more people than there is on earth?

Comment: @NeilMeyer There are almost [7.2 billion people on Earth](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/).

Comment: Can you add one or more sources for this quote, including context?

Comment: Ralph Nader claims that LD50 of plutonium is 3ng/kg (even though other sources place it at 5µg/kg). Still, even such a ridiculously low LD50 estimate is still 3 times higher than that of botox (1 ng/kg).

Comment: What isotope of Plutonium?

Comment: Ok 800 million then?

Comment: Actually, there is a second claim here: Cohens claim that *Plutonium is constantly referred to by the news media as [such]*.  This claim is equally false as the actual content of the claim.

Comment: @gerrit Any isotope of plutonium. The linked document says "Reactor-Pu" (a mix) is 6.5 times as toxic as 239-Pu.

Comment: @NeilMeyer All 7 billion humans can live in Texas at New York density, and potential deaths are theoretical.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In "[The Nuclear Energy Option, Chapter 13, Plutonium and Bombs](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~blc/book/chapter13.html)" (Plenum Press, 1990, ISBN 0-306-43567-5), [Bernard L. Cohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Cohen_%28physicist%29) writes:

> When plutonium oxide, the form in which plutonium would be used in the
>   nuclear industry and also its most toxic form, is inhaled as a fine
>   dust, 25% of it deposits in the lung, 38% deposits in the upper
>   respiratory tract, and the remainder is exhaled. Within a few hours,
>   all of that deposited in the upper respiratory tract, but only 40% of
>   that deposited in the lung, is cleared out. The other 60% of the
>   latter — (.25 x .60 =) 15% of the total inhaled — remains in the lung
>   for a rather long time, an average of 2 years.
>
> [...]
>
> The 2 million fatalities per pound inhaled leaves plutonium dust far
>   from "the most toxic substance known to man." ***Biological agents, like
>   botulism toxin or anthrax spores are many hundreds or thousands of
>   times more toxic.* Plutonium toxicity is similar to that of nerve
>   gas, but given the choice of being in a room with equal quantities
>   of plutonium dust and nerve gas, the latter would be infinitely more
>   dangerous.** It rapidly permeates the room air, whereas plutonium, being
>   a solid material, would be largely immobile.
>
> [...]
>
> The calculational procedure used here to obtain our result, 2 million
>   deaths per pound inhaled, follows the recommendations of the
>   International Commission on Radiological Protection (ICRP). It would
>   be impossible to obtain a very different result without sharply
>   deviating from them; at least three independent investigations have
>   used them to evaluate the toxicity of plutonium and they have all
>   obtained essentially the same result. These ICRP recommendations are
>   used by all groups charged with setting health standards all over the
>   world, such as the Environmental Protection Agency and the
>   Occupational Safety and Health Administration in the United States.
>   They are almost universally used in the scientific literature.
>
> [...]
>
> **It is 5,000 times more dangerous to inhale plutonium than to eat it, and eating plutonium is about equal in danger to eating the same quantity of caffeine.**

He also states that:

> There is no direct evidence for plutonium-induced cancer in humans,
>   but there have been a number of experiments on dogs, rabbits, rats,
>   and mice. The results of these are summarized in [Fig. 1](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~blc/book/chapter13.html#fig1), where the
>   curve shows the expectation from our calculation. It is evident that
>   the animal data give strong confirmation for the validity of the
>   calculation.

[image: Fig. 1 — Results of animal experiments with inhaled plutonium. The curved line shows the predictions of the calculation outlined in the text.]

Comment: I pity the test subject who had to eat plutonium. Very good Answer!

Comment: Don Mastick said it tasted [metallic](http://www.nytimes.com/books/first/w/welsome-plutonium.html). I'm more worried about [Albert Stevens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Stevens) who was secretly injected with 131 kBq of plutonium isotopes.

Comment: Should probably be compared to Po-210, which is dangerous by ingestion as well as inhalation, and which kills by acute radiation poisoning because of it 138 day halflife.

Comment: 'and eating plutonium is about equal in danger to eating the same quantity of caffeine' would be an excellent claim, is it true?

Comment: @dmckee I don't think any nuclear reactor uses phosphate fertilizers or bismuth, so how does Po-210 relate to my answer?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Yes; according to the linked documents, Cohen's paper in refereed scientific journal Health Physics (Vol. 32, pp. 359-379, 1977) passed additional review.

Comment: You've given us references to the dangers of Plutonium as radioisotope, but the question is about "the most toxic substance", and I suspect that even among radioisotopes plutonium takes a back seat to Polonium-210. There is nothing wrong with the facts in your answer, it just doesn't really address the question which claims that there is nothing more toxic.

Comment: @dmckee The nerve gas part already establishes Pu as less lethal, and the sentence before it even gives two examples that are many hundreds or thousands of times more toxic than Pu, so the answer to whether Pu is most toxic is negative.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned by two claims in the answer; one that anthrax and botulism toxin are hundreds of times more toxic than plutonium (BTW that would be the core to the answer to OP question), and that eating plutonion is safer than eating caffeine. I understand that Cohen's paper is in a peer-reviewed journal, but those claims are quoted from his book. Are those backed by scientific references? I take your word for it, no need to put them here.

Comment: [Po-210](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/58088.php) kills at 1 microgram, similar to inhaled [botulism](https://books.google.nl/books?id=3fzYL6virMQC&pg=PA38&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).